# About OSL shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osl

I was learning about the Open Shading Language and I found this. I know that these are codes for creating OSL shaders, but when writing them in Blender, do they have to be written as they are here or just what it is in the brackets? For example - "Diffuse (N)" or just "N"? -

BSDF

diffuse(N)

oren_nayar(N, roughness)

reflection(N)

refraction(N, ior)

microfacet_beckmann(N, roughness)

microfacet_beckmann_refraction(N, roughness, ior)

microfacet_ggx(N, roughness)

microfacet_ggx_refraction(N, roughness, ior)

phong_ramp(N, exponent, colors[8])

diffuse_ramp(N, colors[8])

translucent(N)

transparent()

ashikhmin_velvet(N, roughness)

ward(N, T, roughness_u, roughness_v)

diffuse_toon(N, size, smooth)

glossy_toon(N, size, smooth)

westin_sheen(N, roughness)

westin_backscatter(N, edginess)

hair_reflection(N, roughnessu, roughnessv, T, offset)

hair_transmission(N, roughnessu, roughnessv, T, offset)

Here is the page:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/OSL

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking what OSL is? Or are you asking what the list of functions you included means?

Comment: No, just the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This list of functions you included is a list of BSDF 'closures' that are available in the Cycles render engine using OSL. A 'closure' is explained as follows:

> OSL's surface and volume shaders compute an explicit symbolic description, called a "closure", of the way a surface or volume scatters light, in units of radiance. These radiance closures may be evaluated in particular directions, sampled to find important directions, or saved for later evaluation and re-evaluation. This new approach is ideal for a physically-based renderer that supports ray tracing and global illumination.
>
> In contrast, other shading languages usually compute just a surface color as visible from a particular direction. These old shaders are "black boxes" that a renderer can do little with but execute to find this one piece of information (for example, there is no effective way to discover from them which directions are important to sample). Furthermore, the physical units of lights and surfaces are often underspecified, making it very difficult to ensure that shaders are behaving in a physically correct manner.

See the [OSL Introduction page](https://code.google.com/p/openshadinglanguage/wiki/OSL_Introduction#Surface_and_volume_shaders_compute_radiance_closures,_not_final) for more info.

Put simply, a closure is like a building block for a shader. For each pixel in the final image, the renderer passes various bits of information (surface normal, roughness, index of refraction, etc.) to a closure. The closure returns some sort of information about the reflected light from a surface based on the information the renderer passed it. They're very similar to the shaders (BSDFs) in Cycles. It's just a different language.

You can download some example OSL shaders [here](http://www.openshading.com/osl/example-shaders/)

and a really good introduction to OSL programming in Blender [here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/introduction-to-osl-in-blender-cycles/)

Note: this list of closures is available to the Cycles render engine, but not necessarily any other OSL-compliant render engine; the engine has to provide its own closures.

Comment: bytheway, are the shaders explained or you have to wright it all? For example, "refraction(N, ior)". In the Text editor you have to wright the refraction as "N, ior" or "refraction(N, ior)?"

Comment: When you want to use refraction, you would have to write refraction(N, ior), but 'N' and 'ior' need to be variables that hold the correct values. Also, you'd need to output the value returned by refraction(N, ior). Are you familiar with programming?